# PubSub: Recommended way to save messages using Autobahn Python/WAMP

Tags: autobahn, wamp-protocol

I am using Autobahn to broadcast messages to subscribed clients.  However, when a client is NOT connected to the Internet, it is still necessary that they receive the messages when they reconnect. Will I need to use something like RabbitMQ to accomplish this or can Autobahn handle this natively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutobahnPython](http://autobahn.ws/python/) does not persist messages. Retrieval of [message history](https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/advanced.md#event-history) is an upcoming feature in WAMPv2, and a broker with message persistence will be available as part of [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/).

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn, WAMP and Crossbar.io, and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Hi, Could you explain me how to configure Crossbar.io for message persistance ?

Comment: There is no message persistence (today 2014/12) in Crossbar.io

Comment: @oberstet when is expected to be available "a broker with message persistence"?